# Infinite loop with fsolve

Tags: matlab, infinite-loop

I am dealing with the following function:

```
function opemployment=eqns(unknown);
global kappa theta lgamma beta r delta s x b e gamma v;
varphi=unknown(1);
h=unknown(2);
opemployment(1)=(h^(gamma-1))*((1-kappa)*((lgamma*(varphi^beta))/(gamma*kappa*beta+1-kappa))*h^(gamma*beta-gamma)-(r+delta+s)*(s^(gamma-1))*x^(-gamma));
opemployment(2)=(1-kappa)*(b-e+(kappa/(1-kappa))*theta*v^(gamma-1));
```

and call the function with:

```
close all; clear all;
global kappa theta lgamma beta r delta s x b e gamma v;
kappa = 0.1; theta = 0.5; lgamma = 0.3; beta = 0.5; r = 0.33; delta = 0.91; s = 0.4; x = 0.6; b = 0.4; e = 0.5; gamma = 0.5 ; v = 0.4;
while kappa < 1 && theta < 1 && lgamma < 1 && beta < 1 && r < 1 && delta < 1 && s < 1 && x < 1 && b < 1 && e < 1 && gamma < 1 && v < 1 
    guess = [0,1];
    sol=fsolve('eqns',guess)
    mat = [sol]
    kappa=+0.1;
    theta=+0.1;
    lgamma=+0.1;
    beta=+0.1;
    r=+0.1;
    delta=+0.1;
    s=+0.1;
    x=+0.1;
    b=+0.1;
    e=+0.1;
    gamma=+0.1
    v=+0.1;
end
```

Any ideas why I'm hitting an infinite loop? What I am trying to achieve is to run fsolve for a certain amount of time, store the results in a single matrix as a new row each time fsolve runs and then plot a graph from this (yet to add this line).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're never incrementing any of the variables in the `while` condition. You just set them equal to `0.1` (perhaps you think that there's a `+=` operator in Matlab – there isn't). It's also probably a bad idea to overload the `gamma` and `beta` functions as variables. And there's probably [no good reason to be using globals](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/51946-systematic-do-not-use-global-don-t-use-eval).

Comment: @horchler any idea how can I achieve what I want with MATLAB?

Comment: For starters, increment your variables so they don't stay constant, e.g, `kappa = kappa+0.1;`.

Comment: The `fsolve` call as well as incrementing by `0.1` is invalid MATLAB syntax.  I don't understand how this code can even run.  Would this be Octave?

Comment: It is actually running but catches and infinite loop constantly refreshing the command window